# Needing text in all the rows of the second column to stretch until they are flush against the right margin

Tags: tables

I like the way this table is shown. I just need the contents in the rows and in the second column to be flush against the right margin.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}



\begin{document}
The following list composes the first verses of some old, famous nursery rhymes. They are ``Mary Had a Little Lamb,'' ``Baa, Baa, Black Sheep,'' and ``Hickory, Dickory, Dock.'' All originated in England.

\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\textbf{ }}l}
\textbf{i.) }&{\em Mary had a little lamb, Its fleece was white as snow, yeah. Everywhere the child went, The} \\
&{\em little lamb was sure to go, yeah.} \\
\textbf{ii.) }&{\em Baa, baa, black sheep Have you any wool? Yes sir, yes sir Three bags full. One for my} \\
&{\em master And one for the dame One for the little boy Who lives down the lane.} \\
\textbf{iii.) }&{\em Hickory, dickory, dock The mouse ran up the clock. The clock struck one The mouse ran} \\
&{\em down Hickory, dickory, dock.}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `tabular` environment requires a awful lot of visual formatting. I suggest switching to a customized `enumerate` environment.

Consider the following screenshot. (The framelines on either side of the text block are drawn courtesy of the `showframe` option; omit it in your real document.)

[image]

- The first of three text groups employs the OP's original, `tabular`-based code.
- The middle group switches to an `enumerate` environment, which uses no visual formatting at all. Note the `\raggedright` directive in the "before" option, which is used to make the middle text group be visually nearly indistinguishable from the first.
- The third does away with the `\raggedright` option, so that full justification applies. I think that is what you want.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[textheight=9in,textwidth=6.1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\null % just for this example

\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\textbf{ }}l}
\textbf{i.) }&{\em Mary had a little lamb, Its fleece was white as snow, yeah. Everywhere the child went, The} \\
&{\em little lamb was sure to go, yeah.} \\
\textbf{ii.) }&{\em Baa, baa, black sheep Have you any wool? Yes sir, yes sir Three bags full. One for my} \\
&{\em master And one for the dame One for the little boy Who lives down the lane.} \\
\textbf{iii.) }&{\em Hickory, dickory, dock The mouse ran up the clock. The clock struck one The mouse ran} \\
&{\em down Hickory, dickory, dock.}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape\bfseries\roman*.),
                  labelwidth=3em,
                  before=\itshape\raggedright]
\item Mary had a little lamb, Its fleece was white as snow, yeah. Everywhere the child went, The little lamb was sure to go, yeah.
\item Baa, baa, black sheep Have you any wool? Yes sir, yes sir Three bags full. One for my master And one for the dame One for the little boy Who lives down the lane.
\item Hickory, dickory, dock The mouse ran up the clock. The clock struck one The mouse ran down Hickory, dickory, dock.
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape\bfseries\roman*.),
                  labelwidth=3em, 
                  before=\itshape] % <-- note: no "\raggedright"
\item Mary had a little lamb, Its fleece was white as snow, yeah. Everywhere the child went, The little lamb was sure to go, yeah.
\item Baa, baa, black sheep Have you any wool? Yes sir, yes sir Three bags full. One for my master And one for the dame One for the little boy Who lives down the lane.
\item Hickory, dickory, dock The mouse ran up the clock. The clock struck one The mouse ran down Hickory, dickory, dock.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the comparison of codes using the enumerate environment. From your explanation, it seems that full justification is the default in this environment. What is "labelwidth=3em"?

Comment: @user143462 - An `em` is a typographic length parameter; traditionally, an `em` equals the width of the uppercase letter "M". With the `enumitem` package, `labelwidth` is a length parameter that governs how much space to set aside between the left-hand edge of the text block (indicated by a thin vertical line in the screenshot I posted) and the start of the item's text material. The "label" is the item's marker -- here, a bold roman numeral, followed by `.` and `)`. Since roman numerals tend to take up a lot more space than arabic numerals do, be sure to leave enough space for the labels.

Comment: How do I indent the items? The Roman numeral `iii.)` is typeset too close to the left margin for my liking.

Comment: @user143462 - Well, the spacing in  the `enumerate` examples is *exactly the same* as in the code you provided. :-) Please clarify what constitutes "too close ... for [your] liking". Put differently, how much wider should the indentation be?

Comment: Yes, the Roman numeral `iii.)` was typeset too close to the left margin in the original post. Now that your code with the `enumerate` environment gives me the full justification that I needed, I am asking for one modification to your code. I would like to further indent the Roman numerals - maybe by `3em`.

Comment: @user143462 - I suggest you start by replacing the option `labelwidth=3em` with `leftmargin=4em` or `leftmargin=5em`. (6em might be excessive...)